# If set io.flutter.embedded_views_preview to true, can't run flutter project normally

Tags: ios, flutter

**Flutter (Channel master, v1.9.1-pre.58)**

I write a custom native view and use it by flutter embedded views. Then I  set `io.flutter.embedded_views_preview` to `true` in `Info.plist`. It runs well in iOS Simulator, but when I run on my iPhone, only shows a black screen. It can show other widgets when I **delete** `io.flutter.embedded_views_preview` in `Info.plist`, but this also causes the embedded views can't show.

Answer (score 6):

Setting `io.flutter.embedded_views_preview` flag in ***Info.plist*** is [no longer required for Flutter 1.22 or above](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-views#ios).

> Prior to Flutter 1.22, platform views were in developers preview. In
> 1.22 or above, this is no longer the case, so there’s no need to set the `io.flutter.embedded_views_preview` flag in `Info.plist`.

I suggest to [upgrade](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/upgrading) to the [latest Flutter version](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/release-notes).